# $(\int_0^uf(r,u)dB_r)_{u \geq 0}$ is Gaussian

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}_+\times \mathbb{R}_+\to \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $u>0,\int_0^u(f(r,u))^2dr<\infty.$

Prove that $(\int_0^uf(r,u)dB_r)_{u \geq 0}$ is a Gaussian process.

We note here that $f$ depends of $u$ so that $\int_0^uf(r,u)dB_r$ is not a martingale and we can't apply Ito's formula to prove the exercise.

Perhaps we should find a sequence of Gaussian processes converning in probability to $\int_0^uf(r,u)dB_r$.

Any ideas how to prove the result?

Comment: It is the same proof that shows that $\int_0^u f(r)\,dB_r$ is Gaussian for deterministic $f$. One does not need the Ito-formula to prove this nor the fact that it is a martingale. The proof just shows that the distribution for every fixed $u$ is Gaussian.

Comment: For $f(r)$ this follows from the exponential martingale and Ito's formula

Comment: Wherever it follows from. Everyone has their favourite proof. This surely implies that for any fixed $v$ the integral $\int_0^uf(r,v)\,dB_r$ is Gaussian ($v$ has nothing to do with the integration, nor with the martingale property). Now set $v=u$. Still Gaussian.

Comment: You mean using the exponential martingale for $f(r,v)$?

Comment: This won't work since we do not have $\int_0^u(f(r,v))^2dr<\infty$!

Comment: You have in OP $\int_0^u(f(r,u))^2dr<\infty$. This implies $\int_0^w(f(r,u))^2dr<\infty$ for all $w\le u\,.$ This allows to define $\int_0^wf(r,u)\,dB_r$ which is now Gaussian whenever $w\le u\,.$

Comment: You method doesn't work, we need to approximate.

Comment: In that case, how did you approximate your $\int_0^uf(r,u)\,dB_r$ in OP?

Comment: We need to approximate $f(r,u)$ in a convenient way, not sure how (that is why I asked the question), perhaps step functions would be helpful

Comment: In that approximation we hold $u$ fixed. This is nothing else than approximating $f(r)$ when we integrate it over $[0,u]\,.$ I don't know what proof you have in mind all the time. The one I know is in H. Bauer, *Probability Theory* where it is shown without Ito/martingale that $\int_0^uf(r)\,dB_r$ is Gaussian by approximating this. Now put back that $u$ into $f(r,u)$. A no brainer. Case closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $h(r)$ is locally square-integrable and $t>0$, then the Ito integal $\int_0^t h(r)\,dB_r$ is a mean zero Gaussian random variable.

For ease of reference define $X_u:=\int_0^u f(r,u)\, dB_r$. Fix $u>0$ and apply the preceding remark with  $h(r) = 1_{r\le u}f(r,u)$ and $t=u$ to see that $X_u$  is normally distributed, for each $u>0$. More generally, if $b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n$ are real numbers and $0<u_1<u_2<\cdots<u_n$, apply the initial remark to
$$
h(r) =\sum_{k=1}^n 1_{\{r\le u_k\}}b_k f(r,u_k)
$$
to see that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n b_k X_{u_k}
$$
is normally distributed. This proves that $\{X_u: u>0\}$ is a Gaussian process.

Comment: Your argument works well! In the above comments it was suggested that if for all $u>0,(\int_0^wf(r,u)dB_r)_{w\in [0,u]}$ is Gaussian process then $(X_u)_{u\geq 0}$ is Gaussian, but this argumemt is incorrect, right?